# Detailed of predictions on proc logistic

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I am implementing a logit model in a database of households using as dependent variable the classification of poor or not poor household (1 if it is poor, 0 if it is not):

```
proc logistic data=regression;
    model poor(event="1") = variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4;
run;
```

Using the proc logistic in SAS, I obtained the table "Association of predicted probabilities and observed responses" that allows me to know the concordant percentage. However, I require detailed information of how many households are classified poor adequately, in this way:

[image]

I will appreciate your help with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the CTABLE option to your MODEL statement.

```
model poor(event="1") = variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 / ctable;
```

> [CTABLE](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_syntax22.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en#statug.logistic.logisticctable) classifies the input binary response observations according to
>   whether the predicted event probabilities are above or below some
>   cutpoint value z in the range . An observation is predicted as an
>   event if the predicted event probability exceeds or equals z. You can
>   supply a list of cutpoints other than the default list by specifying
>   the PPROB= option. Also, you can compute positive and negative
>   predictive values as posterior probabilities by using Bayes’ theorem.
>   You can use the PEVENT= option to specify prior probabilities for
>   computing these statistics. The CTABLE option is ignored if the data
>   have more than two response levels. This option is not available with
>   the STRATA statement.
>
> For more information, see the section Classification Table.